Determining the basis for the set that is orthogonal to a given set of vectors.
I was given a question on my samplex:
Which of the following sets is a BASIS for the subspace of V4 consisting of all elements that are orthogonal to both $(0,1,1,1)$ and $(1,1,1,0)$?
A. {(1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1)}
B. {(1,–1,0,1),( –1,1,0,–1) ,(0, 1,–1,0)}
C. {(0,0,0,0), ( –1,1,0,–1) ,(0, 1,–1,0)}
D. {(–2,1,1, –2),(0, 1,–1,0)}
E. {(0, –1,1,0)}
So, the first thing I did was to get the inner product:
let $V1=(0,1,1,1)$ and $V2=(1,1,1,0)$
$<V1,V3>= y+z+t=0$
$<V2,V4>= x+y+z=0$
then, I wrote them in terms of matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&1\\1&1&1&0\end{bmatrix}
from this, I treated $z$ and $t$ as the free variables, the result is:
$x=0$
$y=-z-t$
from this, the basis I got was ${(0,-1,1,0),(0,-1,0,1)}$, which is none of the choices.
My professor said that the right answer is D but I can't fully understand how. However, from what I understood:
(a) B and C has three vectors, so they are automatically wrong.
(b) E isn't sufficient to be a basis, which leaves us with choices A and D.
I'm guessing that D is the correct answer because one of the vectors matches the one that I got. However, I do not understand how $(-2,1,1,-2)$ became one of the elements of the basis. Can you please help me with this? Thank you.

Sol. A is ruled out because the dot product of (0,0,0,1) with either of the two given vectors isn't 0.

Just to note, as Jean Marie said in her comment, the best way to answer this is to check which set of vectors (from A or D) are orthogonal to the two given vectors. Not just is this faster, but also since bases are not unique, after solving your system of equations you will need to play around with different values to get the vectors listed in the answers.
Your method is the right idea but isn't quite there. Let $\underline{u} = \left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{matrix}\right)$. Then
$$M\underline{u} = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}a + b + c\\b + c + d\\\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\\end{matrix}\right)$$
(This is equivalent to just taking the dot product of $\underline{u}$ with the two given vectors and getting two seperate equations)
Then it follows that
$$a = -b-c = d$$
So choosing our two free variables $b$ and $c$ will fix $a$ and $d$. To get the solution D, for the first vector take $(b, c) = (1, 1)$ and for the second $(b, c) = (1, -1)$. Note there are many different choices for $b$ and $c$ all of which are valid bases.
Alternatively you can construct the augmented matrix. Which in this case looks like this
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
And then use elementary row operations (EROs) to get it into row reduced echelon form (RREF). Only then can you read the solutions from the matrix.
